# sort all strings in files and sum the number of each string

Tags: bash

I have multiple files that look like this: (format: `<string>,<number>`).

For example:

```
a,5
b,2
c,3
```

I want to sort and sum all of them so the final output will be

```
<string>,<sum of all numbers>
```

For example two files:

first file:

```
a,5
b,2
c,3
```

second file:

```
a,1
b,2
```

output:

```
a,6
b,4
c,3
```

firstly I would use `cat *` than `sort`. but what should I use next?

Comment: even its possible - if it's not a homework, use python not bash for this type of task

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file1 file2
a,6
b,4
c,3
```

Output order is awk random. Use for example `sort` to order it if needed.

**Edit**: To the commant:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{if(($1 in a)==0||a[$1]<$2)a[$1]=$2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file1 file2
a,5
b,2
c,3
```

Comment: what if I wanted to get the larger number? i mean if a,4 and a,2 it will print a,4 (and not the sum)

Answer (score 1):

Awk is a powerful command, check some tutorials [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_basic_examples.htm). Some specific examples to your needs and for you to understand the concepts of `awk`

Assuming your file is named `file.txt`

`a,5
b,2
c,3`

You can use the following:

```
 awk -F, '{print $2}' file.txt
```

With this you are getting "the second column" delimited by the symbol ',' from the file: `file.txt`.

To sum a column, you can use the following:

`awk -F, '{ total += $2; } END {print total}' file.txt`

That is, use a temporary variable to accumulate each value in the second column.

Finally, you can use the following:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' file1 file2 ... fileN`

You declare the delimiter by using a `built-in` variable of `awk` named `OFS` which stands for, `Output Field Separator Variable`, then you can do a loop adding the second column.

`Note`: `sort` is not needed since the sum is being done by `key`. And also take into account that `... fileN` represents the N files you will send to the script.